# Insertar de forma ordenada con búsqueda binaria

Tags: c++

Quiero insertar en un vector ordenado un elemento de forma que lo inserte para que el vector siga ordenado de menor a mayor. Esta ordenación la prodria hacer de forma lineal, pero he decidido que para que sea más eficiente hacerlo de forma binaria. Es decir, busco con el algoritmo de la búsqueda binaria la posición en la que insertar. Sin embargo, no llego a conseguir que funcione mi código

```
BusquedaBinariaPosInsertar(const int num){
  int izda, dcha, centro;
  bool encontrado = false;

  izda = 0;
  dcha = datos.size()-1;

  while(izda <= dcha && !encontrado){
    centro = (izda + dcha)/2;

    if(datos[centro] >= num){
        encontrado = true;
    }
    else{
        dcha -= 1;
    }
}
```

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: "*no llego a conseguir que funcione mi código*" ¿Y qué es lo que falla exactamente?